# what measure of time do i have here?

Tags: javascript, date, time

If the answer is 8. What is 8? milliseconds? or must I (time/100)-(ntime/100) to get milliseconds?

```
var time=(+new Date());

for(var i=0;i<100;i++){/*something intensive*/}

var ntime=(+new Date());

console.log('answer: '+((ntime)-time)+('( '+time+' , '+ntime+' )'));
```

answer: 8 / 1404573120333 >> 1404573120341

(+new Date()) A unix timestamp is described as the time in **seconds** since the epoch

Comment: If a millisecond is 100 seconds long, then yes. But it's not, so neither the division nor the factor is right (it needs to be multiplied by *1000.*) (First-year high school physics, SI prefixes...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1404573825 would be epoch, seconds since jan1,1970.

1404573120333 is 3 digits longer, most likely milliseconds since jan1,1970

difference therefore too.

Comment: WOW so it adds digits to the end! last 3 are milliseconds? micro and nano? I love the simplicity!! +1

Comment: consider output of   date +%s%N  -> 1404574175994290726

Comment: @8DK: If you display the number in decimal form (base 10), then you can see the milliseconds as the last three digits of the number. For the computer, that uses base 2, it's not that simple.

Answer (score 1):

When turning the `Date` value into a number using the `+` operator, it will call the [`valueOf` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueof). The value returned is the number of milliseconds since 1970-01-01 UTC.

> "The valueOf method returns the primitive value of a Date object as a
>   number data type, the number of milliseconds since midnight 01
>   January, 1970 UTC."

The `valueOf` method returns the same value as the [`getTime` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime). The doumentation for the `getTime` method has this example for measuring time in milliseconds:

```
var end, start;

start = new Date();
for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
  Math.sqrt(i);
end = new Date();

console.log("Operation took " + (end.getTime() - start.getTime()) + " msec");
```